# Findin the most general harmonic polynomial of the form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

The question says to find the most general harmonic form of $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$. And I've seen one or two answered questions here on this topic but I couldn't understand $why$ certain steps were took and didn't see how this was applicable to a 2-degree function.

I'd like some help, if you may.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$. We know that a harmonic function satisfies the equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 0.
$$

We have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2ax + by, \ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 2a.
$$

And
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = bx + 2cy, \ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 2c.
$$

We evaluate the partial derivative with respect to $x$ by considering $y$ to be constant (and vice versa).

Now, we want $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 0$ for all $x$ and $y$. This gives $2a + 2c = 0$, or $c = -a$. It follows that the general harmonic polynomial of degree $2$ has the form
$$
ax^2 + bxy -ay^2.
$$